# Unoconv convert excel to csv with semicolon without quotes

Tags: linux, excel, csv, unoconv

I'm doing a simple command for convert excel to csv with semicolon

```
 unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,34,0,1" filex.xlsx
```

but the results appears with quotes like this

```
"name";"lastname";"age"
```

How could I convert without quotes?

Answer (score 3):

I solve with this

```
     unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,1"  filex.xlsx
```

I use this wiki

```
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Token_8.2C_csv_import
```